# Preload custom font with Next.js

Tags: reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering

Greetings Stack Overflow community! I'm using some custom fonts in my Next.js project using the following CSS:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: OpenSans;
  font-display: swap;
  src: url(./OpenSans-Regular.woff2) format('woff2');
}
```

The thing is that Lighthouse audit it's telling me to preload these `.woff2` files but they are getting hashed by Next.js. I don't know how to add the `link` tag with `rel="preload"` for the fonts.

Where can I tell Next.js to preload these fonts?

Thanks you!

Comment: Does this help: https://codeconqueror.com/blog/using-google-fonts-with-next-js

Answer (score 18):

In newer versions of Next.js this answer is not relevant anymore. But if you are still using old Next.js versions (before app router) this could be useful.

The problem is in Next.js, that the font files get compiled if you place them in any other folder besides public. So if you place them in the public folder and reference them manually, you can be using the link preload like below.

Include them in the Head tag and specify the type for the different font types for browser compatibility. Make sure to reference them correctly in the css as well.

```
<Head>
<link
        rel="preload"
        href="/fonts/yourfont/yourfont.woff2"
        as="font"
        crossOrigin=""
        type="font/woff2"
      />
</Head>
```

```
@font-face {
   font-family: "YourFont";
   font-style: normal;
   font-weight: 900;
   src: url('/fonts/yourfont.woff2') format("woff2"),
   url('/fonts/yourfont.woff') format("woff"),
   url('/fonts/yourfont.ttf') format("truetype"),
   url('/fonts/yourfont.svg#yourfont') format("svg");
}
```

Comment: Should be noted this doesn't work if utilizing the new `app` router and this is for the `pages` router.

Answer (score 8):

You can preload them in your `_document.js` inside the `<Head>` component by adding the following:

```
<link
  rel="preload"
  href="/fonts/inter-var-latin.woff2"
  as="font"
  type="font/woff2"
/>
```

Comment: The thing is that the output file name is hashed when the app is compiled :/

Comment: Anyone have a solution here?

Comment: @TaylorA.Leach Check my answer above - i hope it helps with the hashed solution when compiled

Comment: @nullhook Would that work with `ttf` type as well?

Comment: @DanielRamos the hash is calculated based on the file content, so if you use e.g. https://fontsource.org/ then you just need to ensure the version of your npm lib to be strict in `package.json`. E.g. `"@fontsource/lato": "1.0.0"`. This optimistically ensures that the link is forever constant. It can be changed e.g. when webpack changes its checksum algorithm or whatsoever, but this is highly unexpected and even this happens one day you'd need to adapt one URL in your 'head' section

Comment: @TaylorA.Leach you can place them in the public folder, they won't get hashed and you can target them easily. Look above for my solution.

Answer (score 8):

For **external fonts**, you can simply add the preload link in your head component;

```
<link rel="preload" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Play&display=swap" as="font" />
```

As for the **internal fonts** that you have in your `public` folder, this requires;

- `file-loader` configuration in `next.config.js`, this is to resolve the hashed filename
- Type definition for the fonts
- Then import it into your head

Which you can find my sample below;

---

I created a `Layout.tsx` which wraps my other components, which its main purpose is that there would not be [duplicated meta tags](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/9794#issuecomment-809782607) - But this is unrelated to the question.

Here's the code I have in `Next@10.0.5` - to preload both external and internal fonts.

**App.tsx**

```
function App({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps): JSX.Element {
  const queryClient = new QueryClient();

  return (
    <QueryClientProvider client={queryClient}>
      <Hydrate state={pageProps.dehydratedState}>
        <Provider store={store}>
          <main className="main-container position-relative" data-testid="main-container">
            <HeaderComp />
            <Layout>
              <Component {...pageProps} />
            </Layout>
            <FooterComp />
            <ScrollToTop />
          </main>
        </Provider>
      </Hydrate>
    </QueryClientProvider>
  );
}
```

**Layout.tsx**

```
import fontGilroyBold from "@assets/fonts/gilroy/Gilroy-Bold.woff";

const Layout: React.FunctionComponent = ({ children }) => {
  return (
    <div className="content font-play position-relative">
      <Head> {* next/head *}
        {/* ...metaTags */}
        <link rel="preload" href={fontGilroyBold} as="font" />
        <link rel="preload" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Play&display=swap" as="font" />
      </Head>
      {children}
    </div>
  );
};
```

**next-env.d.ts**

```
...
declare module "*.woff";
declare module "*.woff2";
...
```

**next.config.js**

```
const nextConfig = {
  webpack: (config, { buildId, dev, isServer, defaultLoaders, webpack }) => {
    /**
     * Override some of the existing loaders
     */
    // ...

    /**
     * Font imports in the code repository will be resolved as relative path
     */
    config.module.rules.push({
      test: /gilroy\/.+\.(woff|woff2)$/,
      use: {
        loader: "file-loader",
        options: {
          /** Stolen configuration from pre-existing "config.module.rules[2]" */
          outputPath: "static/fonts/gilroy/",
          publicPath: "/_next/static/fonts/gilroy/",
          limit: 1,
        },
      },
    });

    return config;
  },
};
```

Comment: On importing fonts I am getting Cannot find module error. Any solution on how to resolve it?

Comment: Hi @YashVekaria - can i get more context on that? but if it's related to typescript, most likely you may need to `declare module "*.woff"` in one of your `.d.ts` - This answer has been long outdated, I will also need to update it.